# Initialize GUI components in IntelliJ

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm currently building my first GUI with IntelliJ. I arranged all my components in the GUI Designer unisng a Grid-Bag-Layout. My problem is that in the bound class, no code gets generated to make the application actually look like what I designed, there are only declarations of the different components. According to [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-form-initialization-code.html) said code should be automatically generated when compiling the project and processed to the .class file. But that doesn't seem to happen, as I only get an empty window when compiling and running my project.

Comment: I suggest you look into JavaFX. Swing is fine, It just old.

Comment: Try this: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206940455-GUI-Form-creation-code-not-generated

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. Apparently the JPanel which contains all the components doesn't get added to the JFrame by default. So I had to manually call *add(panel)* in my constructor.